# Generate all expressions from list of numbers equal to a number [PROLOG]

Tags: list, prolog, expression, binary-tree

I am given a list of numbers, for example `[22,45,2,6,7,...]`.

Now I have to **insert** binary operators:  `+`, `-`, `/`, `*` and parentheses `(`, `)` between numbers so that expression is equal to given number *k*.

List **all possible expressions** created by insertions of operators and parentheses that will give sum of *k*.

**Position of numbers in resulting expression have to be fixed, i.e. only insertion of operators and parentheses between or around numbers**

**For example**: given number `k=9` and list `[1,2,3]`, one solution would be `[(,(,1,+,2,),*,3,)]`.
How would I do that?

*[ my current wrong solution ]:*
Right now I know how to evaluate expression like `[1,+,3,*,5]` by going from left to right and eating Operand1,Operator,Operand2 until there is nothing to eat.

But I have to insert parentheses too..

Can anybody sketch a solution or give a hint?

This was an old exam question, and I'm preparing for exam which will be in 3 months, so I'm trying to solve these, but I'm stuck.

EDIT: This is prolog question.

Comment: Please use a bit less boldface in the future. It does not help if you use a lot of boldface because people no longer know where to look.

Comment: Furthermore what do you mean with the order of the numbers have to be fixed?

Comment: That you just have to suitably insert operators and brackets, you cant change list of numbers from [1,2,3] to [2,1,3] - I guess that follows from "insert only" but I stated that explicitly again.

Comment: The first hint is you need to define what you think your rules are before thinking about Prolog. If you can define your rules in normal language terms, then the Prolog can follow. About parentheses specifically, when do you think would be a valid point to insert a left parenthesis or a right parenthesis? For example, you would insert a left paren before a number, and it must be preceded by an operator, a left paren, or nothing. You would insert a right paren after a number, etc. And the parens need to be balanced. Think about the rules and write them down in natural language first.

Comment: `going from left to right and eating...until there is nothing to eat` seems the wrong evaluation strategy. You should account for operators precedence.

Comment: You included the "prolog" tag without other languages indicated, so it's assumed to be a Prolog question.

Answer (score 1):

I think trying to directly build the result list with parentheses while traversing the input is a bad idea. It's easier to build up the syntax tree of an expression whose leaves are labeled with the elements of the given list, then process that in a separate step.

For example:

```
?- leaves_expr([A,B,C,D], Expr).
Expr = leaf(A)+ (leaf(B)+ (leaf(C)+leaf(D))) ;
Expr = leaf(A)+ (leaf(B)+leaf(C)*leaf(D)) ;
Expr = leaf(A)+ (leaf(B)+leaf(C)+leaf(D)) ;
Expr = leaf(A)+ (leaf(B)*leaf(C)+leaf(D)) ;
Expr = leaf(A)+leaf(B)* (leaf(C)+leaf(D)) ;
Expr = leaf(A)+leaf(B)* (leaf(C)*leaf(D)) ;
```

This can be implemented as follows:

```
leaves_expr([X], leaf(X)).
leaves_expr(Leaves, X + Y) :-
    append([L|Left], [R|Right], Leaves),
    leaves_expr([L|Left], X),
    leaves_expr([R|Right], Y).
leaves_expr(Leaves, X * Y) :-
    append([L|Left], [R|Right], Leaves),
    leaves_expr([L|Left], X),
    leaves_expr([R|Right], Y).
```

The `append/3` calls are used to decompose the list of leaves into *non-empty* parts to avoid nontermination problems. **I would be interested in an elegant way of doing this with DCGs.**

Then, given an expression tree like this, we can "output" it again in a fully parenthesized form:

```
expr_parenthesized(leaf(X)) -->
    [X].
expr_parenthesized(X + Y) -->
    ['('],
    expr_parenthesized(X),
    [+],
    expr_parenthesized(Y),
    [')'].
expr_parenthesized(X * Y) -->
    ['('],
    expr_parenthesized(X),
    [*],
    expr_parenthesized(Y),
    [')'].
```

Composing these two parts, we get:

```
?- leaves_expr([A,B,C], Expr), expr_parenthesized(Expr, Parenthesized).
Expr = leaf(A)+ (leaf(B)+leaf(C)),
Parenthesized = ['(', A, +, '(', B, +, C, ')', ')'] ;
Expr = leaf(A)+leaf(B)*leaf(C),
Parenthesized = ['(', A, +, '(', B, *, C, ')', ')'] ;
Expr = leaf(A)+leaf(B)+leaf(C),
Parenthesized = ['(', '(', A, +, B, ')', +, C, ')'] ;
Expr = leaf(A)*leaf(B)+leaf(C),
Parenthesized = ['(', '(', A, *, B, ')', +, C, ')'] ;
Expr = leaf(A)* (leaf(B)+leaf(C)),
Parenthesized = ['(', A, *, '(', B, +, C, ')', ')'] ;
Expr = leaf(A)* (leaf(B)*leaf(C)),
Parenthesized = ['(', A, *, '(', B, *, C, ')', ')'] ;
```

and so on. If you write the easy predicate `expr_value/2` to evaluate such expressions (constructed from numbers at the leaves), you're done.

Answer (score 1):

One way to think about the parenthesis problem without actually putting any parentheses is to use postfix notation. In other words:

```
(a + b) * c
```

turns into:

```
a b + c *
```

which is the following tree in canonical Prolog notation:

```
*(+(a, b), c)
```

Similarly:

```
a + (b * c) ---> a b c * + ---> +(a, *(b, c))
```

For a complete example, with three operands, 1, 2, and 3, and only `+` and `*` as operators, to keep it short, you get:

```
1 2 + 3 + ---> (1 + 2) + 3 = 6
1 2 + 3 * ---> (1 + 2) * 3 = 9
1 2 * 3 + ---> (1 * 2) + 3 = 6
1 2 * 3 * ---> (1 * 2) * 3 = 6
1 2 3 + + ---> 1 + (2 + 3) = 6
1 2 3 + * ---> 1 * (2 + 3) = 5
1 2 3 * + ---> 1 + (2 * 3) = 7
1 2 3 * * ---> 1 * (2 * 3) = 6
```

Looking at the first column, I get the following general idea: you start with *n* operands and *n*-1 binary operators. You push the first two operands on the stack, and need to perform 2**n*-3 more steps. At each step, you either push an operand or apply an operator. You can always push an operand if you still have any left. You can apply an operator only if you have two or more operands on the stack; you will have to reduce the stack at that point.

Backtracking will take care of enumerating all possibilities (so this is a typical brute-force exhaustive search of the solution space). You will have two sources of choicepoints: picking one of the operators; and either pushing or reducing.

With this in mind, I arrive at the following implementation of a predicate that takes a list of operands, a list of binary operators, and gives you a "parenthesized" expression:

```
expr(Operands, Operators, E) :-
    Operands = [A, B|Rest],
    length(Operands, N),
    Steps is 2*N - 3,
    expr(Steps, Rest, [B, A], Operators, E).
```

This pushed the first two operands to the stack and calculated the number of steps left.

```
expr(Steps, Operands, Stack, Operators, E) :-
    (   succ(Steps0, Steps) ->
        next(Steps0, Operands, Stack, Operators, E)
    ;   Stack = [E]
    ).
```

Here I used `succ/2` to count down to 0 and then stop; at the end, the only element on the stack is your expression.

```
next(Steps, Operands, Stack, Operators, E) :-
    push(Operands, Stack, Operands_next, Stack_next),
    expr(Steps, Operands_next, Stack_next, Operators, E).
next(Steps, Operands, Stack, Operators, E) :-
    member(Op, Operators),
    reduce(Stack, Op, Stack_next),
    expr(Steps, Operands, Stack_next, Operators, E).
```

This is where you either push or reduce. The two separate clauses is the first source of choice points; using `member/2` to take one operator from the list is the other.

```
push([X|Xs], S0, Xs, [X|S0]).

reduce([A,B|Stack], Op, [X|Stack]) :-
    X =.. [Op, B, A].
```

Implementing pushing and reducing is trivial. I used the "univ" operator `=..` to make terms like `+(1, 2)` from a list like `[+, 1, 2]`.

With this, you can already ask "how can I use +, *, and parenthesis to make 7 out of [1,2,3]":

```
?- expr([1,2,3], [+,*], E), E =:= 7.
E = 1+2*3 ;
false.
```

This is the most basic "generate and test": you generate arithmetic expressions, then test if they evaluate to a value. If you leave out the test, you can see all expressions:

```
?- expr([1,2,3], [+,*], E).
E = 1+(2+3) ;
E = 1*(2+3) ;
E = 1+2*3 ;
E = 1*(2*3) ;
E = 1+2+3 ;
E =  (1+2)*3 ;
E = 1*2+3 ;
E = 1*2*3 ;
false.
```

One curious detail is that because `+` and `*` are already defined as infix operators, Prolog writes them and even parenthesizes them for you. I don't know if a solution like `E = (1+2)*3` is good enough for you or do you really need `['(', 1, +, 2, ')', *, 3]`. [The other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42657646/1812457) seems to have a working solution for this already. Since here the expression is already a valid arithmetic expression, you would have to adjust it slightly. I would probably write it like this:

```
infix(N) -->
    {   number(N)
    }, !,
    [N].
infix(E) -->
    {   compound(E),
        E =.. [Op, A, B]
    }, !,
    ['('], infix(A), [Op], infix(B), [')'].
```

I also don't know if 1+2+3 = 3+3 = 6 is the same as 1+(2+3) = 1+5 = 6: do you need to consider associativity?

Either way, you can wrap `expr/3` in a predicate like this:

```
equals_k(Numbers, K, E) :-
    expr(Numbers, [+,-,*,/], E0),
    K =:= E0,
    phrase(infix(E0), E).
```

PS: it is quite easy to get a division by zero exception, try for example:

```
?- expr([1,0], [/], E), R is E.
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]This my solution proposal which I find to be simple and straight forward,
copy and paste to notepad++ editor for best readability.

```
* ________________________________________________                           *
*|find_expression(NumsList,TargetValue,Expression)|                          *
**------------------------------------------------*                          *
* Expression is an arithmetic expression of the numbers in Numslist with     *
* possible operators '+','-','*','/' and '(' and ')' between the numbers     *
*  in such a way that the expression evaluates to the TargetValue argument   *  
*****************************************************************************/%

/* a single element number list can evaluate only to itself */ 
find_expression([SingleNumber],SingleNumber,SingleNumber).

/* expression of a multypile number list */ 
find_expression(NumberList,Target,Expression):-

    /* non-deterministically  divide the number list 
     into 2 separate lists which include at least one number each*/ 
    append([X|Xs],[Y|Ys], NumberList),

    /* recursively find an expression for east list, 
       where the expression evaluates to itself */ 
    find_expression([X|Xs],Exp1,Exp1),
    find_expression([Y|Ys],Exp2,Exp2),

    /* non-deterministically  choose an operand from [+,-,*,division] 
       and compose Expression to be (Exp1 Operand Exp2) */ 
    (   member(Expression,[Exp1+Exp2,Exp1-Exp2,Exp1*Exp2]) 
        ; /* prevent zero divison */
        (Val2 is Exp2, Val2 =\= 0, Expression = (Exp1/Exp2))), %/*

    /* assure that final expression evaluates(matches) the targe value 
       and convert value from integer to float if necessary */
    ( Target = Expression ; Target is Expression 
      ; FloatTarget is Target*1.0, FloatTarget is Expression)
```