# Is there a way to create a mathematical expression in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

As another side project of mine for learning Prolog, I was wondering if there is a way to solve this problem. I am trying to make a program that takes as input a list of numbers and adds mathematical operators between them such that the mathematical expression is valid. For example: Input: 5 1 6 11 Output: 5*1+6=11

If there is no way for the mathematical operators to be added so as to create a valid mathematical expression the program will just output a message such as "No possible combination of mathematical operators". I appreciate all answers.

Comment: Do you want to construct the expression tree for an arithmetic expression that must resolve to a given constant? If so, take a look at this: [Generate all expressions from list of numbers equal to a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42650998/generate-all-expressions-from-list-of-numbers-equal-to-a-number-prolog)

Comment: I suppose you can define various rules for each expression, like `add(A,B,C):-C is A+B.` then chain them together in a way that would solve the input two values at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
operator(S, X, Y, R) :- S == '+', R is X + Y, !.
operator(S, X, Y, R) :- S == '-', R is X - Y, !.
operator(S, X, Y, R) :- S == '*', R is X * Y, !.
operator(S, X, Y, R) :- S == '/', R is X / Y, !.

operation(_, [], R, R) :- !.
operation([], _, R, R) :- !.
operation([O|List], [N1|List2], A, R):- operator(O, A, N1, R2), operation(List, List2, 
R2, R).
```

To test it out:

```
operation(['+', '*', '-', '/'], [1, 2, 3, 4], 0, R).
```

Answer

R = -0.25.

Hopefully this works to you!